# node-dirty doesn't persist from run to run

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-dirty

I have the following module :

```
// vote.js
var db = require(./dirty-wrapper);

module.exports = function vote() {

  var obj = {};

  // increase the score
  obj.inc = function(key) {
    var pval = db.get(key);
    if (!pval) pval = 0;
    db.set(key, pval + 1);
  };

  // decrease the score
  obj.dec = function(key) {
    var pval = db.get(key);
    if (!pval) pval = 0;
    db.set(key, pval - 1);
  };

  // reset the score to 0
  obj.reset = function(key) {
    db.set(key, 0);
  };

  obj.get = function(key) {
    return db.get(key);
  };
  return obj;
};
```

Which uses this simple wrapper for dirty:

```
// dirty-wrapper.js
var dirty = require('dirty');
var db = dirty('vote.db');


module.exports = db.on('load', function() {

  var obj = {};


  obj.set = function(key, val, callback) {
    db.set(key, val);
    return callback();
  };


  obj.get = function(key, callback) {
    return callback(db.get(key));

  };

  obj.reset = function(callback) {
    db.forEach(function(key, val) {
     val = 0;
   });
    return callback();
  };
  return obj;
});
```

and this is my simple client :

```
// client.js
var vote = require('./vote.js')();

vote.inc('michael');
vote.inc('michael');
vote.inc('michael');
vote.inc('michael');

console.log('michael: ' + vote.get('michael')); // output = michael: 4
```

Problem is that when the run stops and I start the client again, The output is again `michael: 4`

after the second run, `vote.db` contains the following :

```
$ cat vote.db
{"key":"michael","val":1}
{"key":"michael","val":4}
{"key":"michael","val":4}
{"key":"michael","val":4}
{"key":"michael","val":1}
{"key":"michael","val":4}
{"key":"michael","val":4}
{"key":"michael","val":4}
```

First, would be great if someone would explain the `append-only` strategy. Second I would like to understand why node-dirty doesn't persists even though it writes to the disk each run.

Thanks ;)

Comment: I think I mixed `sync` and `async` functions here, it causes some problems, just not really sure what the rule of thumb here is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the database before it has loaded, and are essentially starting from 0 every time.  `module.exports` runs immediately, but the `load` event has to wait for the disk io.
You have to wait for the file to be loaded and parsed before you get values from the db.

From the [readme](https://github.com/felixge/node-dirty#dirty-event-load-length):

> dirty event: 'load' (length)
>
> Emitted once the database file has finished loading. It is not safe to access records before this event fires. Writing records however should be fine.

You can remove the `dirty-wrapper` file, and just use `vote` as the wrapper.  Make a minor change to how you are using it, keeping in mind that you have to wait for the load event.

Your vote interface:

```
// vote.js
var events = require('events');
var dirty = require('dirty');
var db = dirty('vote.db');

var obj = new events.EventEmitter();

// increase the score
obj.inc = function(key) {
  var pval = db.get(key);
  if (!pval) pval = 0;
  db.set(key, pval + 1);
};

// decrease the score
obj.dec = function(key) {
  var pval = db.get(key);
  if (!pval) pval = 0;
  db.set(key, pval - 1);
};

// reset the score to 0
obj.reset = function(key) {
  db.set(key, 0);
};

obj.get = function(key) {
  return db.get(key);
};

db.on('load', function() {
  obj.emit('load');
});

module.exports = obj;
```

And your main script:

```
// client.js
var vote = require('./vote.js');

vote.on('load', function() {
  
  vote.inc('michael');
  vote.inc('michael');
  vote.inc('michael');
  vote.inc('michael');
  
  console.log('michael: ' + vote.get('michael')); // output = michael: 4  

});
```

This will output 4 more votes every run.

Comment: Thanks ! I would like to keep the dirty-wrapper so I could maintain a single interface if I want to switch to other db. I will experiment a little and try.